# Undefined method/NoMethodError in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods

When i access http://localhost:3000/users, it gives me `NoMethodError in Users#index`. The error is as follows:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index

Showing /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rails_projects/TUTORIALS/todo/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <% @users.each do |user| %>
2:   hello!! <%  @user.name %>
3: <% end %>
Rails.root: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rails_projects/TUTORIALS/todo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/users/index.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___3451413751309771876_2169723860_4451603425222664605'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:1:in `each'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___3451413751309771876_2169723860_4451603425222664605'
```

My model user.rb:

```
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email
```

My view app/views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  hello!! <%  @user.name %>
<% end %>
```

My controller app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @users = User.all  
  end
```

My routes.rb file has:

```
resources :users
```

All my tests pass (using rspec) including the test case in spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
     it "should be successful" do
       get 'index'
       response.should be_success
     end
end
```

When I access http://localhost:3000/users/1, it shows me the users perfectly. Codes in app/views/users/show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>
```

I have done rake db:test:prepare and I think the error is linked to the db or migrations. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It would help us if you showed us the NoMethodError you were getting.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks! Just added the error at the start of my question! I did rake db:reset and then rake db:migrate, rake db:test:prepare. Still it show the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  hello!! <%  @user.name %>
<% end %>
```

It should be:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  hello!! <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

In your code the object `@user` does not exist, that's why you get the error. In the iteration each user in `@users` is put into the `user` object one-by-one.

Another mistake in your code is that you were using `<% @user.name %>`. This does not output anything. If you want to output the name of the user you have to use `<%= user.name %>` (notice the equal sign).

Comment: Thanks mischa! Both of your suggestions for (1) no @ and (2) put the = sign for ruby embed worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  hello!! <%  user.name %>
<% end %>
```

`user`, not `@user`?